# node js mysql error unexpected end of input

Tags: mysql, node.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs= require('fs');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var conn = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: '111222',
  database: 'o2'
});
conn.connect();


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 

app.get(['/topic', '/topic/:id'],function(req,res){
  var sql= 'select id, title *from topic';
  conn.query(sql, function(err, rows, fields){
    res.render('new',{topic:rows});

  });



app.locals.pretty = true; 
app.set('view engine','pug'); 
app.set('views','./views');  



app.listen(3000,function(){
  console.log('connect!');
})`enter code here`
```

I want to create a web page using node js, but I don't know why there is an error. 
I want to create a web page using node js, but I don't know why there is an error.

Comment: You have an unwanted `*` in the sql query, is this a typo?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs= require('fs');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var conn = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: '111222',
  database: 'o2'
});
conn.connect();


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.locals.pretty = true;
app.set('view engine','pug');
app.set('views','./views');

app.get(['/topic', '/topic/:id'],function(req,res) {
  var sql = 'select id, title *from topic';
  conn.query(sql, function(err, rows, fields) {
    res.render('new', { topic: rows });

  });
});
app.listen(3000,function(){
  console.log('connect!');
});
```